# Vue 3 - "Failed to resolve component" warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs3, es6-modules

I have this warning when i try to import components from my index.js file.

Here is my components folder:

```
components/
|-- index.js
|-- ComponentA.vue
|-- ComponentB.vue
|-- ComponentC.vue
```

and index.js:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
import ComponentC from './ComponentC';

export { ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC };
```

When i am trying to do this in any component (B or C)

```
<script>
import { ComponentA } from './';

console.log(ComponentA); // undefined

export default {
    components: { ComponentA }
}
</script>
```

I have a warning in my console, so how to fix it? What am i doing wrong here?

By the way, this works:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
```

But i don't want to use this method because i have many components in `components` folder

Answer (score 0):

You should write the import statement as follows :

```
<script>
import { ComponentA } from './components';

export default {
    components: { ComponentA }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If i do like this the path would be `components/components` and this code will produce error. What is strange, it **works** only for external directory,  but in `components` directory path `./` doesn't work.